# Possible unintended reference comparison using arraylist and button

Tags: c#

```
ArrayList hafiza = new ArrayList();
string sql = "";
sql = "SELECT koltuk_adi FROM Koltuk";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, baglanti);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();



 if (dr.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= hafiza.Count; i++)
                {
                    hafiza[i]=(dr["koltuk_adi"].ToString());
                }
            }

String btn ="";
            for (int j=0;j<=hafiza.Count ;j++)
            {
                for (int i=1;i<70;i++)
                {
                    btn = "button"+i;
                    if(this.Controls[btn].Text == hafiza[j])
                    {
                        this.Controls[btn].BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                        this.Controls[btn].Enabled = false;
                    }
```

`Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type 'string' array...`

I'm getting this error on `if(this.Controls[btn].Text == hafiza[j])` line.

Comment: Don't use an `ArrayList` anymore but a strongly typed `List<string>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing an `object` with `string`. Since they are not the same type, C# will compare their references, which is usually not what you want. (In this case the result always will be `false`)

Use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList` to type the value of `hafiza[j]`.

(Note you have to use `Add` on `List<T>` instead of array assignment you currently use)

Comment: I dont even know how to use list<string>, can you edit my code?

Comment: Don't worry. It isn't that hard. Give it a try. If you have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: [NewCodes](http://pastebin.com/gZMv9Ysj)
[NewErrorPic](http://tinypic.com/r/wa25na/8)

Comment: @CemB.: I guess there is no control with that name?

Comment: on errorpic you can see this.Controls[btn] is null. It has to be button43 there is the problem.

Comment: Well, then fix it... This is getting off-topic for this question. If you need more help on this, please ask a new question and give us the code and how to reproduce this (so we need the control layout too).